# Нужна ли запятая перед выражением в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация

Как пояснили в кол-центре торговой компании, «провели разработки согласно изменениям в УФ (уставном фонде)».

Answer (score 1):

Ну конечно нужна! У нас же есть ещё незакавыченная часть предложения — **там**!

А перед «провели разработки согласно изменениям в УФ (уставном фонде)» — нет. (Шёпотом: а зачем?!!)

---

С учётом комментария о внесённой в вопрос правке. Было:

*Как пояснили в колл-центре торговой компании, «провели разработки согласно изменениям в УФ (уставном фонде)».*

Приходится додумывать ряд действий компании, предшествующих, а к ним уже присоединяется колл-центр с пояснением дословным. Всё равно — какие проблемы с запятой?

У нас бессоюзное сложное предложение:

основа 1 — пояснили;

основа 2 — провели, —

но это не однородные члены: колл-центр поясняет, сотрудники компании проводят.

КАРОЧ: ЗАПЯТАЯ НУЖНА!

Comment: «_У нас же есть ещё незакавыченная часть предложения — **там**!_» === У автора вопроса «там» не было. Оно появилось после правки вопроса другим участником.

Comment: Тогда вместо **там** должно быть **они**. 8-( Сейчас попытаюсь посмотреть, что было до правки. Ога. Ну так нужны эти там-они. Предположим, разъяснения остались за кадром; запятая нужна - перед «провели разработки согласно изменениям в УФ (уставном фонде)».